# How to conclude $|a|<|b|$ from $a<\frac{b^2}{a} \text{ and } \frac{a^2}{b}<b$? (Direct Proof)

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

The original question is to prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $a^2 < b^2 \Rightarrow |a| < |b|$.

I was able to easily prove this by proving that its contrapositive, $|a|\ge|b| \Rightarrow a^2 \ge b^2$, is true.

Now, I wanted to try to prove it using a direct proof, so here is what I did:

$\begin{align}
 a^2 < b^2  & \Rightarrow & a < \frac{b^2}{a} \text{ and } \frac{a^2}{b} < b \tag{1}
\end{align}$

This looks complicated because either or both $a$ and $b$ can be negative and furthermore, one or both of them can be $0$. Lastly, I am not able to build a common expression, say $x$ such that I can conclude $a<x<b$.

So, suppose I need to prove this directly, how should I do it and would you have done what I did at (1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach which does not require knowing anything about the square root function.

$a^2 < b^2 \implies b^2 - a^2 > 0 \implies (b-a)(b+a) > 0$
which implies that $b-a$ and $b+a$ are nonzero and have the same sign. Therefore one of the following is true:

1. $b > a$ and $b > -a$, so $b > |a|$, so $|b| > |a|$
2. $b < a$ and $b < -a$, so $b < -|a|$, so $-b > |a|$, so $|b| > |a|$

In either case we have $|a| < |b|$, so we conclude that $a^2 < b^2 \implies |a| < |b|$.

Answer (score 1):

We can say $a^2<b^2\implies|a|^2<|b|^2\implies|a|<|b|$,

where we can justify the last inequality using the fact that $y=\sqrt{x}$ is increasing, or using $|a|^2<|b|^2\implies|b|^2-|a|^2>0\implies(|b|-|a|)(|b|+|a|)>0\implies|b|-|a|>0\implies|b|>|a|$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly shuffling the letters around isn't leading anywhere, so try another approach.

Squaring is increasing for positive numbers, and $x^2=|x|^2$.

$$|a|<|b|\implies|a|^2<|b|^2\implies a^2<b^2$$